# C++ Class methods that compare any type to true

Tags: c++

I am trying to use templates to write a little test class that, for simplicity's sake, can check if any type is equal to true or equals another value.

```
// generic value of some sort
template<class T>
class Value {
    public:
        T value;
};

// generic tester class
class Test {
    public:
        Value value_;
        Test();
        ~Test();
        void SetValueToTest(Value value){
             this->value_ = value;
        }
        bool IsTrue(){
             return this->value_ = true;
        }
        template<class T>
        bool IsEqual(T value){
            return this->value_ = value;
        }
};
```

So far I have this main error

```
error: invalid use of template-name ‘Value’ without an argument list
```

I think it wants me to specify the type, like `<int>` but that would defeat the purpose of trying to test *any* type as true, equal to something else, etc..

Comment: Make `Test` a template as well.  Pass the template parameter down to `Value`.

Comment: If `Value` is a class template (and it is), then you need to provide template arguments. It is *likely* you can do this via making your `Test` class a template and pushing the template argument type down to `Value`. At that point it is feasible to consider the class template `Value` as potentially worthless, and all of this could just be done with `template<class Value>` as the template argument list for `Test`

Comment: @WhozCraig I am intrigued by removing the `Value` class.. Would I be able to call my Test methods without specifying types, ie `<int>` etc? I was banking on being able to use templates to avoid specifying any value types. I sort of thought that was the point.

Comment: Is 1 true? How about 2? Yet 2 is not equal to 1. I think that `IsTrue` needs to return, not whether something is equal to `true`, but whether it is _not_ equal to `false`

Answer (score 1):

`Value` is not a type, it is a class template. `Value<int>` is a type, `Value<double>` is a type, etc.

You can make `Test` a class template to be able to use `Value` in it.

Here's a demonstrative program:

```
// generic value of some sort
template<class T>
class Value {
   public:
      T value;
};

// generic tester class
template<class T>
class Test {
   public:
      Value<T> value_;
      Test() {}
      ~Test() {}
      void SetValueToTest(Value<T> value){
         this->value_ = value;
      }

      bool IsTrue(){
         return (this->value_.value == true);
      }

      template<class T2>
         bool IsEqual(Value<T2> value){
            return (this->value_.value == value.value);
         }
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   Test<int> a;
   a.SetValueToTest(Value<int>{20});
   std::cout << std::boolalpha << a.IsTrue() << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::boolalpha << a.IsEqual(Value<short>{20}) << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::boolalpha << a.IsEqual(Value<short>{30}) << std::endl;
}
```

and its output

```
false
true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Value is a template, you should create an instance of it by declaring the generic value, like `Value<int>` or `Value<char>`. Without that, it doesn't make any sense to the compiler.
Also in your functions you are using `=` (to assign a value) instead of `==` (to compare between values). This means you just return the Value member in Test class after assigning a new value to it.
Finally, since you called the class Value and it's member by the same name, you are trying to compare the Value class instance to true, instead of its internal value.
Fix that and your code should work.